# Ubuntu doesn't boot, vesafb missing

Tags: boot

when i try to boot ubuntu 11.04 i get this result:

FATAL: Error inserting vesafb (/lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/initrd/vesafb.ko): No such device

it stucks here. i can see it when i press ctrl alt f1. in the f7 screen it stucks in the 5 dots. 
I want to recover my system or at least i want to copy my very important files that exist in there. I am sure i had chosen to enqrypt my files.
and i think it happened when i tryied to install oneiric version.
Please Help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Finally i didn't managed to recover my system but i resqued my cryptographed files, using this tutorial

http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/